# App set for 'iPhone', but it still stretches to full screen on an iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've tried to submit my 'iPhone' app to the App Store, however they reject it with an error citing that it needs to operate on an iPad at iPhone resolution. I assumed it would do this automatically, as I have my app set as an 'iPhone' app, not a universal app. And yet, for some reason, my iPhone app still tries to stretch to full screen when running on an iPad. See screen shot below.

[image]

Apple Store came back with:

**Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility**

We noticed that your app did not run or display as expected when viewed on iPad running iOS 11.1. Please see attached screenshots for details.

**Next Steps**

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure it runs as expected and displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad. Even if your app was developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use your app on iPad.

--

On a phone, it appears properly:

[image]

The constraints on all scrollviews are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an iPad sized launch image in your project? Not sure if that is the issue, but it's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: @meaning-matters I do not. And for some reason the iPad stretches my iPhone launch image to full screen as well.

Comment: Does it fill the full iPad screen without any black borders and is there no (1X) button in the bottom right corner?

Comment: @meaning-matters There are black borders and a 1x button in the bottom right corner. That said, tapping the 1x button just downsizes the "maximized" problem (e.g. resolution is still off as if being stretched full-screen, just small).

Comment: That's okay then; it's normal that your app stretches. What details did Apple supply or did get when asking about this? There must be something else.

Comment: @meaning-matters See their official response above (edited question).

Comment: What do the screenshots tell you?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the problem? It is behaving as an iPhone only app just fine, from what you say.

Comment: @matt screen shot added to question :)

Comment: The problem here is not that it runs on the iPad but that the view you have created doesn’t work when displayed on the iPad. Are you using AutoLayout to set up your views? Can you show how you are setting up the views? You need to fix that.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, I'm using autolayout; but that's because I want each view to size automatically to both iPhone 6 or 6Plus (for example). Can I not use autolayout if it needs to run as an iPhone app on iPad?

Comment: Looks to me like it wouldn’t work on an iPhone 5 and that’s the real issue. Have you tried every simulator?

Comment: Yes, you should def be using AutoLayout. Just wanted to check that you were. It looks like the width of your table view is too big. Can you show some code or the storyboard you are using to create your views.

Comment: Make your work on an iPhone 4 and it will work on an iPad.

Comment: @Fogmeister I do have the view sizes set to 'Freeform' - should I change to Inferred / fixed instead? Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Switch to inferred and now you can try different device sizes right there in the design canvas. You will see the issue immediately.

Comment: @matt Did that and everything still looks fine in storyboard. Also just noticed: Under View > Content Mode it's set to 'scale to fill' - should this be something else? Aspect Fit?

Comment: @rmaddy Wow, you would be right. Changed the dimensions to that of iPhone 4 (god forbid) and it now looks fine on iPad. WTH LOL. So if I'm storyboarding, should I always size for iPhone 4? I thought the 4 was a paperweight...

Comment: @Brittany Your storyboard and its layout and constraints should make it work on any sized iPhone: the 4, 5, 6/7/8, 6+,7+,8+, and X. It just so happens the iPad runs iPhone-only apps at the iPhone 4 size.

Comment: @rmaddy If this is the case, and my storyboard view controllers are sized at iPhone 6 size (with the appropriate constraints around each view), why aren't they sizing themselves down to iPhone 4 size on the iPad? See image above in edit - that's how all of my constraints are set.

Comment: just TBSTBS in your "constraint panel" image, you have to click the button at the bottom "Add 4 constraints".  note the edited image in my answer @Brittany, "You must see what is shown in the red boxed area."

Comment: @Fattie In case you're curious - setting storyboard controller sizes to 320x480, and then using the auto-resize constraints solved my issue! I'd post more details with a full answer, but someone closed my question? Also not sure why :/

Comment: Hi @Brittany - ok, I know just what you mean.  In a situation where "setting the storyboard controller size" to something, actually changes the outcome when running: that absolutely, definitely, means that you are missing a constraint somewhere.  Just as I mention in my answer, It was an incredibly silly decision by Apple that: IF you totally omit a needed constraint on a view it will still "work", inferring info. from storyboard in a silly way. **You have a classic case of this**.

Comment: FYI I edited the images to a better size (feel free to edit back if you wish).  One thing, notice the **image in my answer**.  that's how you show the "constraints you have at the moment".  Your image (that's just the "helper box") does *not* actually tell us all the constraints you have.  If you can be bothered, please put in an image "like mine", and do that for BOTH the scroll view per se, AND, the item that is the contents of the scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

Good question - it's likely you are suffering this simple problem:

in autolayout, you have to constrain all views.

Sometimes you forget to constrain a view (or perhaps all of them!)

In some simple cases, the view will still "work".

In your case, by bad luck as it were, the main views are still "working", they are filling up the screen reasonably.

To get you started make sure all four constraints - left, right, top bottom - are attached.

[image]

***(You must see what is shown in the red boxed area.)***

It was an **incredibly stupid decision** by Apple: to try to make things "easier", if you totally omit constraints on a view it will still "work" (it tries it's best to fit it in, using some defaults from your Xcode behaviour or something, which is totally stupid).

It's a remarkably bad idea Apple had: it should, of course, simply not compile if constraints are missing. (Sure, in unusual cases you could put them in at run time or whatever, and flag it; but as a rule it's a plan mistake.)

Again, if you forget **one** constraint, it will bring up an error.  But very confusingly if you **forget them all**, it will **not** bring up an error or even a warning!

And you'll get precisely the problems you describe.

It could well be you are suffering some other issue, but this is the usual simple problem.

Comment: Constraints are all on. Also: who down voted this and why? I'm curious.

Comment: Ah, constraints are on!   You're pretty sure right?  (voting on the site has been random for a couple years - don't worry about it  :O )